# having a problem about my codes in PagesController

Tags: laravel-5

Hi I'm having a problem about my codes in my PagesController.

I'm wondering what is the error about the notification it says undefined variable but it has the same codes in countOrder and countProduct and those two are working just only the notification

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\CustomerOrder;
use App\Product;
use App\Notification;
use DB;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
  public function count() {
    $countOrder = CustomerOrder::count();
    $countProduct = Product::count();
    $notification = Notification::count();
    return view('/adminIndex',['customer_orders' => $countOrder],['products' => $countProduct],['notifications' => $notification]);
  }
}
```

Comment: paste the full exception and it probably points you towards the variable.

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views; right now you're passing 3 arrays of variables (likely truncating the 2nd and 3rd), but it should be a single array with 3 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a few issues here.

Firstly, when passing data to a view, you must use **one** array (rather than several):

```
return view('/adminIndex', ['customer_orders' => $countOrder, 'products' => $countProduct, 'notifications' => $notification]);
```

Secondly, the first argument of the `view()` helper expects the view file (found in the `/resources/views` folder). So if the file is `adminIndex.blade.php` use:

```
return view('adminIndex', ['customer_orders' => $countOrder, 'products' => $countProduct, 'notifications' => $notification]);
```

Hope this helps.